# How to use Html.RenderAction in SparkView Engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

I am getting an error when I use it like this

```
!{Html.RenderAction("Action", "Controller")}
```

I had to switch to webforms view engine and  replace it with

```
<% Html.RenderAction("Action", "Nav"); %>
```

to get it to work.

The error I am getting is "Cannot convert void to char"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<% Html.RenderAction("Action", "Nav"); %>
```

is the same as

```
# Html.RenderAction("Action", "Nav");
```

in Spark syntax. {} expression expects a result to be returned and written to the stream; RenderAction does not return nothing, it writes to the stream itself. That's why you have to call it inside code block and cannot do this inside expression.

Comment: I also had to change my controller action method from returning a View to a PartialView.

Answer (score 4):

Web forms:
`<% %>` = server code
`<%= %>` = server code that `Response.Write(x)` where x == statement

Spark:
`#` == `<% %>`
`${}` == <%= %>

Comment: Not quite, in Spark, `!{} == <%= %>`. `${}` performs HTML encoding before writing out.